# How to sum rows that start with the same string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-analysis

I used pandas to clean a csv:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Leo90\Downloads\data-export.csv',encoding='utf-8', header=None, sep='\n')
df = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
df=df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
df=df.replace(to_replace='None',value=np.nan).dropna()
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
columnNames = df.iloc[0] 
df = df[1:] 
df.columns = columnNames
df.groupby('path').head()
```

The processed data like the screenshot below

[image: Original data]

I want to use python to make this dataframe look like this

[image]

I know I could use `str.contain` to match these strings but it can only return bool, so I can't sum the A&B columns. Are there are any solutions for this problem?

I tried `str.contain` to match these strings but I can't sum A&B.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) on the starting string:

- If the starting string is fixed, use [`.str[:n]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) to slice the first `n` chars

  ```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'path': ['google.com/A/123', 'google.com/A/124', 'google.com/A/125', 'google.com/B/3333', 'google.com/C/11111111', 'google.com/C/11111113'], 'A': 1, 'B': 2})
  #                     path  A  B
  # 0       google.com/A/123  1  2
  # 1       google.com/A/124  1  2
  # 2       google.com/A/125  1  2
  # 3      google.com/B/3333  1  2
  # 4  google.com/C/11111111  1  2
  # 5  google.com/C/11111113  1  2

  start = df['path'].str[:12]  # first 12 chars of df['path']
  out = df.groupby(start).sum()
  #               A  B
  # path              
  # google.com/A  3  6
  # google.com/B  1  2
  # google.com/C  2  4
  ```
- If the starting string is dynamic, use [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to capture the desired pattern (e.g., up to the 2nd slash)

  ```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'path': ['A.com/A', 'A.com/A/B/C', 'google.com/A/123', 'google.com/A/124', 'google.com/A/125', 'google.com/B/3333', 'google.com/C/11111111', 'google.com/C/11111113'], 'A': 1, 'B': 2})
  #                     path  A  B
  # 0                A.com/A  1  2
  # 1            A.com/A/B/C  1  2
  # 2       google.com/A/123  1  2
  # 3       google.com/A/124  1  2
  # 4       google.com/A/125  1  2
  # 5      google.com/B/3333  1  2
  # 6  google.com/C/11111111  1  2
  # 7  google.com/C/11111113  1  2

  start = df['path'].str.extract(r'^([^/]+/[^/]+)', expand=False)  # up to 2nd slash of df['path']
  out = df.groupby(start).sum()
  #               A  B
  # path              
  # A.com/A       2  4
  # google.com/A  3  6
  # google.com/B  1  2
  # google.com/C  2  4
  ```

  Breakdown of `^([^/]+/[^/]+)` regex:

  | regex | meaning |
  | --- | --- |
  | `^` | beginning of string |
  | `(` | start capturing |
  | `[^/]+` | non-slash characters |
  | `/` | slash character |
  | `[^/]+` | non-slash characters |
  | `)` | stop capturing |

Comment: If it has other rows like A.com/A, this method may can't work, how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Because this way need the path must has the same start strings

Comment: Because the real data have many other webpage path, I think this method is only useful if the first few strings of path are the same

Answer (score 0):

Group by the path whilst disregarding the final subpath and aggregate (sum) the other columns.

```
df['path'] = df["path"].apply(lambda x: "/".join(x.split("/")[:-1]))
df.groupby("path").sum()
```